# Exception in Application start method java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when using parse Double

Tags: parsing, javafx

So, I am attempting to get a GUI working for a programming project. This involved changing it from a simple scanning function to converting the userinput from the text field using parse Double. The program was able to function, but once I made the change it throws the exception in the title and terminates the program every time I run it. Yes, I do have a main method.

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class TaxProject extends Application implements 
EventHandler<ActionEvent>
{
private Stage primaryStage;
private Button button;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    TaxInput t1 = new TaxInput();
    StateTax s1 = new StateTax();   //Declaring Classes
    FedTax f1 = new FedTax();
    GridPane pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    pane.setVgap(8);
    pane.setHgap(10);


    TextField tfHrlyWage = new TextField();
    TextField tfHrsPerWeek = new TextField();
    TextField tfMaritalStatus = new TextField();
    TextField tfIncome = new TextField();
    Button btCalculate = new Button("Calculate");
    pane.add(new Label("Hourly Wage: "), 0, 0);
    pane.add(new Label("Hours Per Week: "), 0, 1);
    pane.add(new Label("Married or Single? "), 0, 2);
    pane.add(btCalculate, 0, 3);
    pane.add(tfHrlyWage, 1, 0);
    pane.add(tfHrsPerWeek, 1, 1);
    pane.add(tfMaritalStatus, 1, 2);
    pane.add(tfIncome, 1, 0);




    tfHrlyWage.setPrefColumnCount(4);
    tfHrsPerWeek.setPrefColumnCount(3);
    tfMaritalStatus.setPrefColumnCount(7);
    tfIncome.setPrefColumnCount(7);


    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 250,150);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Tax Calculator");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    String MaritalStatus;  //Used for deciding federal income tax brackets
    //System.out.println("Please Enter your Hourly Wage:");
    t1.HrlyWage = Double.parseDouble(tfHrlyWage.getText()); //HourlyWage Input
    //System.out.println("Please Enter the hours you work per week:");
    t1.HrsPerWeek = Double.parseDouble(tfHrsPerWeek.getText());
    MaritalStatus = tfMaritalStatus.getText();
    btCalculate.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println("Your Yearly Income After Federal and State Income Taxes is $" + f1.YearlyTakeHome));
```

Comment: `t1.HrlyWage = Double.parseDouble(tfHrlyWage.getText()); //HourlyWage Input` This maybe be a good programming in `C++` and `C#`, but it's not in `Java`.

Answer (score 1):

The `start` method is simply setting up the GUI. Nothing makes the code wait for user input the way a console program with a scanner would.

JavaFX is event based and you should find some event/property to add a event handler/listener to and react on events/changes.

This could be a listener to the `text` property of the `TextField`s, if you want to automatically update the result on a change of the text field content

```
//t1.HrlyWage = Double.parseDouble(tfHrlyWage.getText());
//t1.HrsPerWeek = Double.parseDouble(tfHrsPerWeek.getText());

InvalidationListener listener = o -> {

    try {
        t1.HrlyWage = Double.parseDouble(tfHrlyWage.getText());
        t1.HrsPerWeek = Double.parseDouble(tfHrsPerWeek.getText());

        // TODO: some output???
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // TODO: output error message???
    }

};

tfHrlyWage.textProperty().addListener(listener);
tfHrsPerWeek.textProperty().addListener(listener);
```

or from the listener to the button event handler:

```
//t1.HrlyWage = Double.parseDouble(tfHrlyWage.getText());
//t1.HrsPerWeek = Double.parseDouble(tfHrsPerWeek.getText());

btCalculate.setOnAction(e -> {
    try {
        t1.HrlyWage = Double.parseDouble(tfHrlyWage.getText());
        t1.HrsPerWeek = Double.parseDouble(tfHrsPerWeek.getText());
        // TODO: use properties for some calculations???
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        // TODO: display error message???
    }

    System.out.println("Your Yearly Income After Federal and State Income Taxes is $" + f1.YearlyTakeHome);
});
```

Comment: @Andrew if the post solved your problem, accept it as the correct answer.